# Tweetable Mathematics

Tags: ho.history-overview, big-list

**Update**: Please restrict your answers to "tweets" that give more than just the statement of the result, and give also the essence (or a useful hint) of the argument/novelty.

> I am looking for examples that the essence of a notable mathematical development fits a tweet (140 characters in English, no fancy formulas).

Background and motivation: This question was motivated by some discussion with Lior Pachter and Dave Bacon (over Twitter). Going over my own papers and blog posts I found very few such examples. (I give one answer.) There were also few developments that I do not know how to tweet their essence but I feel that a good tweet can be made by a person with deep understanding of the matter.

I think that a good list of answers can serve as a good educational window for some developments and areas in mathematics and it won't be overly big.

At most 140 characters per answer, single link is permitted. Tweeting one's own result is encouraged.

**Update:** I learned quite a few things, and Noam's tweet that I accepted is mind-boggling.

Comment: *I have discovered a truly remarkable proof of this [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) which this Tweet is too small to contain.*

Comment: Gil, are you going to be asking for soundbites next?

Comment: Misha, what is a soundbite? (Never mind I googled it, interesting idea. We did ask about pictures, and about formulas, but I am not aware of the top of my head of mathematical content via audio which is not via language.)

Comment: in a different direction: [Tweetable Mathematical Art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35569/tweetable-mathematical-art)

Comment: I feel like most of the answers are mis-interpreting the question. This doesn't ask for a result whose **statement** is in 140 characters; that would be too broad: most paper titles fit in them. It asks for a result whose essence is tweetable: given the tweet alone, a mathematician with good knowledge of the field can fill in the details and complete a proof. So I am going to downvote almost all of them.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: what is it, a kind of joke? Could you please indicate to me where *exactly* in the question it is written that the tweet should be such that "a mathematician with good knowledge of the field can fill in the details and complete a proof"? Honestly, I do not think that your *personal interpretation* of the locution "essence of a notable mathematical development" should be taken as a rule here.

Comment: @Ycor: yes, I agree. That said, I think that downvoting 14 answers on a personal interpretation basis is questionable, at best.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi why do you tell me this? I haven't downvoted anything in this thread (so far)

Comment: @Ycor: my comment on downvoting was intended to Federico Poloni, not to you. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: This is something I strive for in my own tweets, and I think I have at least a few examples in my twitter feed: http://twitter.com/JDHamkins.

Comment: While I don't quite agree with Federico Poloni's interpretation, I don't understand how this question is not far too broad?  Lots of results can be distilled into aphorisms once you assume enough.  Where does one make the cutoff?

Comment: Perhaps the next big MO question should be, "What is the _essence_ of a mathematical result?" I myself lean toward Federico's interpretation- pithifying a theorem's statement does not necessarily clarify or illuminate the ideas at play.

Comment: My initial intention was indeed that the "tweet" gives more than just the statement of the result but also the essence of the argument/novelty. To demand that a mathematician in the field can fill the details is too much to ask for.

Comment: Answers have been posted as actual tweets in reply to: https://twitter.com/JDHamkins/status/857251368553373696.  Please tweet your own answers there!

Comment: There is a key difference between MO and Twitter: here, posts also have a *lower* bound of 30 characters, as I found by attempting to tweet Descartes.

Comment: I think I'd enjoy the same question much more if it instead asked for theorems in the form of haiku. :-)

Comment: Any particular reason why this question become protected, when in fact it specifically asks for "a good list" of answers? Not having posted to mo before, I am of course unable to post an answer as I don't have the requisite reputation. Well... maybe I'll just waste my time elsewhere, then!

Comment: @ViktorToth it has been protected *automatically* by the system after having two answers by low-rep users (<10) deleted. A moderator or >15k user could unprotect it.

Comment: Gil, the tug-of-war over closing and re-opening this *question* would be my first candidate for a list of *soundbites* if you ever request this.

Comment: @Glorfindel I figured that much, I was just hoping that a moderator might notice my annoyed grunt :-)

Comment: Lots of good examples in the history of the sadly defunct https://twitter.com/tinyproof

Comment: Inspired by Todd Trimble.  "A single number, as a triplet of many, must be less than three."   Fermat's last theorem.

Comment: @Viktor: Wasting your time elsewhere is a good idea. See you there.

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer Thank you for your kind words. You know the thing is, I foolishly composed an answer to this interesting question before I noticed that I am not welcome here on account of not having posted to this particular site before. Your welcoming words are testament to the quality and professionalism of this site and its moderators, I presume. Thank you for introducing yourself.

Comment: I guess the unique goal of the edit is to get new reopening votes?

Comment: Dear Yves, regarding reopening, in view of the very board interpretation of the question,  I myself had mixed feelings about it, and, for this question, did not vote. However, now that the initial stream of answers anyway ended, I like the idea of useful real-time mathematical tweets in rare cases when (and if) a major tweetable advances  will occur.

Comment: Are 280 symbols long tweets acceptable now?

Comment: Maybe there should be a parallel "commentable mathematics" -- results that can fit in an MO comment. And its arcane cousin "previewable mathematics" -- mathematical questions which are short enough that the full text of the question fits into the question preview that you see on the MO question page (you have to select a tag to see this -- otherwise you only see the question title).

Comment: Someone said that 140 characters of Tweet did not give enough space for a certain marvelous proof, his name started like Ferma...

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Every rational r is xyz(x+y+z) for some rational x,y,z.
Proof: Euler (1749) found x(r),y(r),z(r).  Nobody knows how.

I have a guess.
[https://people.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/euler_14t.pdf](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eelkies/euler_14t.pdf)

Comment: And there are some simpler than Euler's x(r), y(r), and z(r). See https://mathoverflow.net/q/302933/24165 .

Comment: Thank you for that reference.  I already found x,y,z a bit simpler than Euler's, but not nearly *that* simple!  Now I should revisit this to figure out if and how the Klyachko-Mazhuga-Ponfilenko fits into the elliptic-fibration picture . . .

Answer (score 180):

Four color theorem: any planar graph can be colored with 4 colors. Only proof by computer. SAD.

Comment: Expressing the essence of how it can be reduced to a huge finite problem for computer proof would be nice, though...

Comment: As years pass by (and more so if we go outside USA) the probability that someone gets the pun tends to zero. SAD.

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: @LutzMattner It's a political joke about Donald Trump, president of America (2016-202?). He likes to say "SAD!" and it's made into jokes.

Comment: Many such cases!

Comment: Okay... what is the pun? Six years have passed by, I am inside the USA, and I don't get it. Is SAD an acronym/initialism for something?

Comment: Not really a pun. As @MaudPieTheRocktorate says, this is just a from of "speech" that Trump used on Twitter in his (first) electoral campaign: e.g. "The Democrats don't have a plan to plunder Mars... SAD" (SAD just being all caps sad). i.e. he is asserting that something is true, and then saying that there is something lacking about it.

Answer (score 122):

27⁵ + 84⁵ + 110⁵ + 133⁵ = 144⁵. Nice try, Euler.  [link](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1966-72-06/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3.pdf)

#Counterexamples

Comment: You can shorten it and make it friendlier to read using Unicode superscript numeral characters.

Comment: How do we do it? (without using Tex, say on Twitter)

Comment: 27⁵ + 84⁵ + 110⁵ + 133⁵ = 144⁵.

Comment: @GilKalai you can express x to the n as x^n with the use of the caret

Comment: @Restioson: I originally typed it out that way, but R.. commented that it is in fact possible to tweet superscript numerals, so I changed it to make it more readable. I was able to type out the superscript 5's in my answer -- without MathJax -- by copy/pasting from this website: http://txtn.us/tiny-text.

Comment: @GilKalai are there still exponents? For me on the stack exchange app I just see the bases...

Answer (score 117):

The sentence "The first positive integer that cannot be specified in a 140 character tweet" doesn't specify a well defined integer.

Comment: In other words, "There are non-tweetable positive integers, but there is no smallest non-tweetable positive integer. Contradiction."

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but assuming a base-10 representation, is 10^140 not the smallest non-tweetable positive integer?

Comment: We mean tweetability in plain languages and mathematical formulae, not just base-10 representations.

Comment: You can tweet: "Ten to the power 140"

Comment: @彩音M https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox

Comment: An integer $x$ whose Kolmogorov complexity $K(x)=141$.

Answer (score 91):

Not deep, but if [0,1]² is cut in N triangles of equal area, N is even. If not, extend 2-adic valuation on Q to R, tricolor plane and apply Sperner.

Comment: This is my favorite! Perhaps it would even benefit from removing the humble "Not deep".

Comment: I like it too, and it suggests a nice general pattern for tweetable mathematics: (1) Statement, (2) Setup, (3) "Apply [known result]."

Comment: #MonskysTheorem

Answer (score 89):

Chebyshev said, and I say it again,
there is always a prime between n and 2n.
#BertrandsPostulate

Comment: Where n = 0? If you have space, maybe include that n > 0

Comment: Well, its not really me who invented this tweet... 
(Also, then I should perhaps also include that $n$ is a natural number and not from some unique factorization domain or whatever)

Comment: yeah, there just might not be enough chars for that...

Comment: I wish Paul Erdos had a twitter account.

Answer (score 85):

Integral of exp(-x²) dx over R = Γ(1/2) = √π.
Proof: square the Gaussian integral and use polar coordinates!

Comment: This is a great example!

Answer (score 65):

Erdos: You can color edges between √2ᵏ vertices red/blue so no monochrome size k subgraphs (Pick a random coloring.  It probably works)

Comment: Perfect example! I love this one.

Comment: It's even a counterexample to Gil Kalai's comment that "To demand that a mathematician in the field can fill the details is too much to ask for."

Answer (score 58):

The n-th binary digit of π is calculable without calculating all the previous digits.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2173610/272831

Comment: Amazing to know!

Answer (score 48):

There are infinitely many primes p for which there is a prime between p+1 and p+246.

Comment: One can add "Still want to know about p+3".

Comment: The reference would fit too:  https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4897

Answer (score 42):

Euclid: there are infinitely many primes, if not, multiply all and add 1. [Link](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/infinite/euclids.html)

If only they had Twitter back then. They had so many tweetable proofs :)

Comment: There are infinitely many composites: Multiple the first n of them. Don't add 1 (attributed to Hendrik Lenstra)

Comment: @JavaMan: that proves that if there are *at least two* composites, then there are infinitely many…

Comment: Also, don't forget [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/622/).

Comment: Better:  "Euclid:  there are arbitrarily many primes, by multiplying those given and adding 1."

Comment: This phrasing can support a common misunderstanding of the proof though. I would end with: "...and add 1; then factor."

Answer (score 41):

**33 = 8866128975287528³ + (-8778405442862239)³ + (-2736111468807040)³.** Andrew Booker! [link](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2019/03/09/8866128975287528%C2%B3-8778405442862239%C2%B3-2736111468807040%C2%B3/).

Update 2019-09-05: $(-80538738812075974)^3 + 80435758145817515^3 + 12602123297335631^3 = 42$, https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~maarb/. This completes all the numbers less than $114$.

Comment: This is fantastic!!!!! (Read the link if you didn't already know why.) Honestly, this looks like a winning answer.

Comment: Tim Browning deserves a tradable digital trophy for this solution. This is a computational problem which is easy to verify, difficult to solve, and of mathematical significance. One should be able to construct a cryptocurrency smart contract that can reward someone for solving this kind of problem. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322022/what-solutions-to-useful-computational-problems-could-be-rewarded-through-crypto

Comment: @JosephVanName I do really like and like to think about your linked question - however, as you kind of hinted at, if Andrew Booker were to be awarded merely for his solution, he would be demotivated to actually publish his methods, lest others copy!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/223121/88133

Answer (score 39):

The most beautifully useless theorem of mathematics IMO:

"This statement is a theorem (and moreover, I can prove it)" — [link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273791)

Comment: Can I get you interested in joining the [tautology club](https://xkcd.com/703/)?

Comment: @Mindwin Ah, but the amazing thing about these "Henkin sentences" is that they are not so trivial to prove.

Comment: This made my world that much bigger. Thank you.

Answer (score 38):

$AB-BA=I$ has no solution in finite matrices. Pf: Trace it!

Comment: Except void matrices ($n=0$ :)

Comment: $AB - BA= I$ not solvable in Banach algebras. Pf: Spectra of AB and BA.

Comment: Except when the dimension is equal to zero in the coefficient ring (e.g. $M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{F}_2)$).

Answer (score 35):

$n!$ divides $(2^n-1)(2^n-2)(2^n-4)\cdots(2^n-2^{n-1})$.

Proof: $\mathfrak{S}_n$ embeds in $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{F}_2)$. $\quad \square$

(I have read this elegant justification on MO someday, yet I do not find it now.)

Comment: What does the fancy $\mathfrak{S}_n$ stand for, symmetric group on $n$ letters?

Comment: @StefanPerko Absolutely!

Comment: Nice! But I think it should be $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbf{F}_2)$ rather than $\operatorname{GL}_2$.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Thanks for the correction

Comment: For someone without a clue I do not know whether the third term in the product is supposed to be $2^n-3$ or $2^n-4$. I guess the latter makes more sense.

Comment: @M.Winter Good question. It is $2^n-4$ (then $2^n-8$, and so on). The reason is that $|\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbf{F}_2)| = (2^n-1)(2^n-2)(2^n-4)(2^n-8)\dotsm(2^n-2^{n-1})$. And the reason for *that* is that if you build an invertible matrix column by column, after choosing the first $k$ columns, the next column to be chosen out of the $2^n$ possible vectors must not lie in the span of the first $k$ columns, which is a $k$-dimensional subspace so it has $2^k$ elements, leaving $2^n-2^k$ choices for the $(k+1)$st column.

Comment: The factorial can be expressed as a q-Pochhammer product or series as well is confirmed with this very statement. This factors a $2^n^n$.

Answer (score 31):

Halting problem - there is no computer program which can determine if an arbitrary computer program halts on a specified input. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Answer (score 29):

You cannot comb a hairy ball, should you wish to.

Comment: The wind always stands still somewhere.

Comment: Hairy donuts on the other hand...

Answer (score 19):

Sphere packing-The E8 lattice provides the optimal packing in eight-dimensional space. [Link](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2017/185-3/p07)

Comment: Still within the twitter limit :) : Sphere packing-The E8 lattice provides the optimal packing in eight-dimensional space, Pf: LP+modular forms https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.04246

Answer (score 19):

Mihăilescu's theorem (ex Catalan conjecture) - $8$ and $9$ are the only consecutive proper powers of natural numbers. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture)

Comment: first proved in 2002? WOW

Answer (score 18):

Borsuk's conjecture - a counterexample for DIM>2000, the tensor product of the unit sphere with itself. [Link](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/borsuks-conjecture/)

Answer (score 18):

Wedderburn's theorem-Every finite skew field is a field. Pf: class equation on centralizers and cyclotomic irreducibility. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem)

Comment: Edited to give some idea on the "essence" of the proof.

Comment: Alternative proof (not to be confused with "alt-proof"): apply Chevalley(-Warning) to the norm form.

Answer (score 17):

Turing discovers problems that even computers cannot solve. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Comment: You won't believe the second, and the fifth blew my mind!

Comment: @PeterSamuelson I don't get it. Second what, fifth what?

Comment: @Todd, it is an internetism, to get people to click on a link to a list of, oh, money saving incredible mathematical tweets?  Gerhard "Using This One Weird Tip" Paseman, 2017.04.26.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Oh yes, I've seen that. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 17):

Breaking News: A mathematician blew up 6 points on a plane! You won't believe what happened [next](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_surface#27_lines_on_a_cubic_surface)...

Comment: BREAKING NEWS: a plane got blown up by a mathematician. At least five cups of coffee are thought to be dead.

Answer (score 16):

Cantor's theorem!

> The cardinality of the reals is greater than that of the natural numbers.

Also, various incompleteness results along the lines of the [Mathematical T-Rex](http://karagila.org/2015/mathematical-t-rex/):

> The continuum hypothesis is neither provable nor disprovable from ZFC, unless ZFC is inconsistent to begin with!

(The above can be extended to include a myriad of choice-related statements and ZF, for example.)

Comment: You still have room to mention "diagonalization" and "forcing", respectively, if we are to focus on the "essence of a notable mathematical development" aspect. If you split "CH isn't provable..." and "CH isn't disprovable…" into two tweets, you could accommodate the constructible universe, too.

Answer (score 16):

One more:

[CFSG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups) - The [largest sporadic simple group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_group) has order 808017424794512875886459904961710757005754368000000000.

Comment: Oops, that was two links, so it doesn't fit the conditions. Feel free to ignore either - the two Wikipedia pages have direct links to each other.

Comment: Is there any intrinsic definition of sporadic group? Out of curiosity, I'd like to know if any other finite simple group was once considered as sporadic (= not abelian, alternating, or in any "list" of Lie-flavor type) before it was extrapolated as Lie type.

Answer (score 15):

Of course, every finite group of odd order is solvable.

Comment: I'd like to see the essence of this development on a tweet. :)

Comment: I have discovered a truly remarkable proof of this theorem which this <s>margin</s>tweet is too small to contain.

Comment: Savage one ....

Comment: Proof: Apply CFSG ;-)

Answer (score 15):

Invert 2×2 matrix A?  Easy: switch diagonal entries, negate off-diags,
& divide by Δ=det(A).
Pf: divide A²-tA+ΔI=0 by A, solve for 1/A !

[MO link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89069/should-the-formula-for-the-inverse-of-a-2x2-matrix-be-obvious/89080#89080)

Answer (score 14):

Lindemann's theorem - You need more than a compass and a ruler to square a circle. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)

**Edit** Or if we really want the essence of the argument, on which a whole lot of stronger results have been patterned since:

Exploiting the properties of the exponential function, if $\pi$ was algebraic there'd be rational integer strictly between 0 and 1.

Comment: OK, I'll stop now… :)

Comment: Well, Lindemann's theorem is much more than this. "Lindemann's theorem: pi is transcendental" would be better.

Comment: Sure. I intentionally toned it down so as to mean something to a broader audience, who might not want to expend the extra time to follow a link...

Comment: Lindemann's theorem does **not** say $\pi$ can be approximated too well by rationals to be algebraic.  As far as we know, $\pi$ is not particularly well approximated by rationals.

Comment: Thank you @Robert Israel. Fixed the toned-up version (I hope).

Answer (score 14):

One among $\pi+e$ and $\pi e$ is irrational. Proof: If not, then $(x+e)(x+\pi) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and hence $e$ and $\pi$ would be algebraic.

NOTE: It is still open whether either of $\pi+e$ and $\pi e$ is irrational.

Comment: "One" meaning "at least one".

Comment: Yes, but that would get me over the 140 character limit. ;-)

Comment: It might be better to say that it is still open whether either of $\pi + e$ and $\pi e$ is *rational*.

Answer (score 14):

This is actually a [real tweet](https://twitter.com/BooleanAnalysis/status/1145837576487612416) by Ryan O'Donnell on [Huang's proof](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.00847) of the sensitivity conjecture.

> Hao Huang@Emory:
>
> Ex.1: ∃edge-signing of n-cube with 2^{n-1} eigs each of +/-sqrt(n)
>
> Interlacing=>Any induced subgraph with >2^{n-1} vtcs has max eig >=
>   sqrt(n)
>
> Ex.2: In subgraph, max eig <= max valency, even with signs
>
> Hence [GL92] the Sensitivity Conj, s(f) >= sqrt(deg(f))

Comment: See also: https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2019/07/02/amazing-hao-huang-proved-the-sensitivity-conjecture/

Answer (score 14):

det(exp(X)) = exp(tr(X)). Remarkably, the RHS does not involve off-diagonal elements of X.

Answer (score 13):

The prime numbers contain arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions.

Answer (score 13):

1_000_000 $ problem solved: every simply connected, closed 3-manifold is homeomorphic to the 3-sphere. Hint: use the Ricci flow.

Answer (score 13):

Lagrange: every integer is sum of 4 squares. Pf: 4-squares identity + every real prime splits in the ring of Hurwitz quaternions. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem)

Answer (score 12):

Banach–Tarski paradox: a solid sphere can be divided in a finite # of parts which can be joined to form 2 spheres identical to the original.

Comment: Too many characters. :-)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen true. Let's cheat a bit on the grammar, and use # for something else than a #hashtag.

Comment: "finite # of parts" -> "5 parts" save some more bites. Feels like code-golfing…

Comment: Can the idea in the proof be distilled into 140 characters? "Banach-Tarski: AC + free group actions create unmeasurable ghost sets in the sphere; these become two same-volume spheres, from one!"

Comment: A long haired cat or a samoyed can be used very effectively for demonstration...

Answer (score 12):

Here are three.

Wiles theorem: Every elliptic curve over Q is parameterized by modular functions.

Faltings Theorem/Mordell Conjecture: A curve of genus at least 2 has only finitely many rational points.

Faltings Theorem/Shafarevich Conj: There are only finitely many abelian varieties with good reduction
outside a given finite set of primes.

Comment: "Wiles theorem" actually has several other authors; I think all five can be accommodated within the 140-character limit.

Answer (score 12):

[Borsuk–Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem):

If you crumple a ball and run a steam roller over it there are at least two antipodal points touching.

Answer (score 9):

No surjection f from S to its powerset. If so, let T = {x in S | x notin f(x)}. Must be some y such that f(y)=T. Then y in T iff y notin T!#

(140 characters, nothing fancy)

Answer (score 9):

This question is actually much older than what it appears to be. The famous **fundamental anagram of calculus** (Newton, 1676)

> 6accdae13eff7i3l9n4o4qrr4s8t12ux

is an anagram of the Latin

> Data aequatione quotcunque fluentes quantitates involvente, fluxiones invenire; et vice versa

(less than 140 symbols). In modern English it means

> Given an equation involving any number of fluent quantities to find the fluxions, and vice versa

or, in Arnold's interpretation

> It is useful to solve differential equations

Answer (score 9):

This is based on a real [tweet](https://twitter.com/BooleanAnalysis/status/1216917564334448643) of Ryan O'Donnell on the [proof](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04383) of **MIP*=RE** which disproves Connes' Embedding Conjecture from 1976.

> MIP* = RE, by Zhengfeng Ji, Anand Natarajan, Thomas Vidick, John
>   Wright, Henry Yuen: https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04383 . There is a
>   multiple-entagled-quantum-provers proof system for the Halting
>   Problem, and Connes' Embedding Conjecture is false.

Answer (score 8):

Gödel's first incompleteness theorem - any consistent formal system capable of basic arithmetic is incomplete. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#First_incompleteness_theorem)

Answer (score 8):

If Ax = y underdetermined w unique sparse soln x0, minimizing L1(x) recovers x0 under mild conds. Shannon-Nyquist bad (or sick) thm! [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_sensing)

Answer (score 8):

Few things multiply nicely (division rings usually noncommutative) but few things multiply nicely (finite ones are) #Wedderburn

Answer (score 8):

A rectangle tiled by rectangles with an integral side has an integral side because it has mass zero under a certain periodic signed measure.

(Tweeted [here](https://twitter.com/ejenk/status/857428314927050752))

Answer (score 8):

Every set of integers with divergent reciprocals contains 3-term arithmetic progressions. Erdos and Turan conjectured; Bloom and Sisask proved; Bateman and Katz's method for cap set used.  [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.03528).
#TWTMTH

Comment: post: https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2020/07/08/to-cheer-you-up-in-difficult-times-7-bloom-and-sisask-just-broke-the-logarithm-barrier-for-roths-theorem/

Answer (score 7):

How about a proof that, given a set, there always exists a bigger set?

> For every set A, there is a set that doesn't inject into A. Take the
>   set B of ordinals that inject into A. B is an ordinal and is not in B.

I think one can also fit a proof of [Sylvester's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) in 137 characters.

> Take n points not on a line. Let L be a line containing >1 points
>   minimizing the distance to a point off L. It contains exactly 2
>   points.

Comment: Can you ensure that B is not a proper class within the tweet limit?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: No. The tweet assumes the familiarity of the reader with the axiom of replacement.

Answer (score 7):

Littlewood's [example](https://archive.org/stream/mathematiciansmi033496mbp#page/n30/mode/1up) of a 2 line dissertation fits here, I believe.

An integral function never 0 or 1 is a constant:

$\exp(i\Omega(f(z)))$ is a bounded integral function

Comment: Just seen this. Shouldn't it be "entire function"?

Comment: @YemonChoi It is the way Littlewood writes, but you are right, current terminology is "entire". Shall I change it nevertheless? Can't decide...

Answer (score 7):

Cole 1903: 2^67-1=147,573,952,589,676,412,927=193,707,721 × 761,838,257,287  #MoreThanThreeYearsOfSundays

Answer (score 6):

There is an algorithm to compute étale cohomology in finite time (but we don't know how long it takes) — [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5376)

Answer (score 6):

> Weyl's law: pack a domain with tiny squares. In the limit, hear the domain's volume.

and

> Polya's theorem: pack a square with tiny domains. In the limit, the domain is always higher-pitched than Weyl's law thinks it should be.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I can't make sense of this. How do I hear something by/after packing?

Comment: Which Pólya's theorem does this refer to? Searching, I find the Pólya enumeration theorem.

Comment: @cfh "On the Eigenvalues of Vibrating Membranes," 1961, Proc LMS (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/plms/s3-11.1.419/abstract). A domain that tiles Euclidean space has every Dirichlet eigenvalue greater than the value predicted by Weyl's law.

Comment: @Dirk Curious ignorance needs no pardon :) c.f. xkcd 1053. This refers to the eigenvalues of the Laplacian on a domain with (Dirichlet) boundary condition. One can interpret them as squared frequencies of standing waves, so associate them with harmonic tones of a domain. Weyl's law says that the asymptotics of this sequence encodes the volume of the domain. As the Laplacian is elliptic, there's a variational principle that ends up allowing one to compare eigenvalues across domains; Weyl's law can be proven by tiling with squares (which have computable eigenvalues) and making that comparison.

Comment: That's pretty cool, thanks for the explanation! (Now try to explain that in a tweet...)

Answer (score 6):

Cap set problem solved: polynomial method, punchline going back to (a+b)²=a²+b²+2ab. [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.09223)

Comment: I actually tweeted it and a few more under the hashtag #TWTMTH

Answer (score 6):

A finite(dimensional) domain has to be a field: all nonzero "multiply-by-an-element" maps are self-embeddings.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way of pretending that any reduced ring is Noetherian and a field. Grothendieck's generic freeness lemma is then quite easy. [link (Section 11.5)](https://rawgit.com/iblech/internal-methods/master/notes.pdf#page=88)

Answer (score 5):

**ΕΥΡΗΚΑ num=Δ+Δ+Δ
(Every positive integer can be written as the sum of three triangular numbers, Gauss, July 10, 1796)

Answer (score 5):

$S$ unit sphere of an $\infty$-dim Banach isn't compact. Pf: for $H$ closed hyperplane, $\bigcap(S\cap H)=\varnothing$ (Hahn-Banach), but no finite subintersection is empty.

**Note:** $\infty$, $\bigcap$, $\cap$, $\neq$, and $\varnothing$ are unicode characters, so this is actually tweetable!

Comment: Shouldn't $\ne$ be $=$?

Comment: Thanks @AndrésE.Caicedo, I correct!

Answer (score 4):

Stark-Heegner theorem: There are nine imaginary quadratic fields with class number one. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark%E2%80%93Heegner_theorem)

Answer (score 4):

I can't resist. Birkhoff's theorem:

For an erg measure-pres trans, orbit-wise avgs of a fn agree with the spatial avgs.

Answer (score 4):

Cubum autem in duos cubos, aut quadratoquadratum in duos quadratoquadratos & generaliter nullam in infinitum ultra quadratum potestatem in duos eiusdem nominis fas est dividere cuius rei demonstrationem mirabilem sane detexi. Hanc marginis exiguitas non caperet.

Not in English, 268 characters so two tweets, @Glorfindel 's comment,  but I couldn't not post it.

Comment: Dear Ethan, warm regards--Gil

Comment: The canonical answer

Answer (score 4):

Trichotomy: the rational points on an algebraic curve are parametrizable; form a finitely-generated abelian group; or form a finite set.

Answer (score 4):

The square of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares of the other two sides.

Answer (score 4):

Every non-constant complex polynomial has a complex root : If not the inverse is bounded analytic. Use Liouville. #FundamentalTheoremOfAlgebra

Answer (score 4):

Not a theorem but a good result on Mersenne integers  using Lucas-Lehmer test (via @toorandom)

*2^74207281-1 is #prime, they checked:
Consider s_1=4, s_2=14,...,s_j=(s_{j-1}^2)-2...
m=(2^n)-1 prime <=>
s_{n-1} is multiple of m #mathchat*

Answer (score 4):

Aubrey de Grey's strategies for finding the chromatic number of the plane: A) prolonging life to 1000 years and waiting for a solution B) Constructing a unit-distance planar graph that requires 5 colors!!! Based on SAT-solvers and a lot of Moser Spindles. [link](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2018/04/10/aubrey-de-grey-the-chromatic-number-of-the-plane-is-at-least-5/)

Comment: The above far exceeds 140 characters. A more straightforward version works: “Aubrey de Grey constructed a unit-distance planar graph that requires 5 colors!!! Based on SAT-solvers and a lot of Moser Spindles.”

Answer (score 4):

"The Magic Words Are [Squeamish Ossifrage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Words_are_Squeamish_Ossifrage)" - to factor a 129-digit semiprime took way less than 40 quadrillion years when early-90's era computers work together using early-90's era factoring algorithms over the early-90's era Internet!

Answer (score 4):

One cannot hear the shape of a drum. [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9207215)

Proof via [Sunada's Theorem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/318b/ff9d5e5885364fcf873549c18b069aa87bc1.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiq08yqi7vkAhUFheAKHcLUCwkQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw2t3RwM8vUDy33v9h7_FXAm).

Answer (score 4):

Lucas-Lehmer for Wagstaff. Let $p$ be an odd prime,
$s_0=4,s_{n+1}=s_n^2-2$, then $N_p=(2^p+1)/3$ is prime implies
$N_p$ divides $s_{p-1}-5-9\left( \frac{p}{3} \right) $.

Answer (score 3):

ZFC + "exists a Reinhardt cardinal" is inconsistent.

V = L implies that measurable cardinals do not exist.

Answer (score 3):

f_N = (-d/dx)^N cos(x^½)
= A(y)f_0 + B(y)f_1 for y = 1/(4x); A,B∈Z[y], deg O(N)
~ N!/(2N)! as N → ∞ = o(ε^N)
f_1/f_0∈Q ⇒ y∉Q
x = π^2 ⇒ π^2∉Q

Answer (score 3):

Elliptic curves produce a key exchange that may be safe against quantum computers. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersingular_isogeny_key_exchange)

Comment: They do? That is awesome.

Comment: "May be".  That is, nobody knows of a sub-exponential quantum algorithm in the supersingular case, because the known sub-exponential algorithms for ordinary elliptic curves require the endomorphism ring to be commutative.  But I see no reason for confidence that a sub-exponential quantum algorithm for this case does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

The smallest positive integer not definable in under sixty letters.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental theorem of algebra: every polynomial splits in the field of complex numbers.

Answer (score 3):

e^x is sum of x^k/k!, k=0,1,...: Binomial theorem on (1+x/n)^n; coefficient of x^k is binom(n,k)/n^k=(1-1/n)...(1-(k-1)/n)/k!→1/k! as n→∞

(137 characters, uses fancy Unicode characters)

Answer (score 3):

First, my original tweet, on the essential content of IUT, i.e. how it intends to prove ABC, in 140 characters:

> mochizuki: invented big deformation machine-tracks how deformed
>   schemethry needs before HA-thry applies-amount of deformation IS
>   Spziro ineq

Now, Twitter recently raised the character limit for all users to 280 characters, so with my whopping 140 extra characters, I will write a new style tweet of the same flavor:

> Mochizuki: Invented deformation machine-IUT-which elim. obstruct'ns
>   from applying fund.thm.of HAtheory to schemethry by deforming
>   schemethry. By measuring distort. needed b4 FTHAT applies, ineq.
>   appears-this is content of Spziro conj. hence ABC, modulo rigor
>   check:IUT black box

Comment: oh and I should say, HA theory is Hodge-Arakelov theory, Mochizuki's initial framework for solving ABC

Comment: This looks a good piece of ciphetext!

Answer (score 3):

Lattices with exponential kissing number discovered by Serge Vlăduţ. Another home run for algebraic-geometry codes. [Link](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2018/02/27/serge-vladut-lattices-with-exponentially-large-kissing-numbers/).

Actually, with the new 260 characters policy we can add:

Lattices with exponential kissing number discovered by Serge Vlăduţ. Another home run for algebraic-geometry codes. Will exponential improvement for Minkowski's 1905 lower bound for sphere packing be the next grand slam?

Answer (score 2):

Every consistent first-order theory has a model of countable size.

A set of sentences is consistent if and only if every finite subset
is consistent.

A set of sentences has a model if and only if every finite subset of it has a model.

The first order logic is the only logic with a finitary syntax to possess the Löwenheim-Skolem property and be complete.

Answer (score 2):

Only nonbinary nontrivial perfect code is ternary w parity matrix rows 11122010000 11210201000 12101200100 12012100010 10221100001. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound#Perfect_codes)

Answer (score 2):

Sz(q) has two orbits more than PSL(2,q) under the action of its automorphism group - see https://doi.org/10.1081/AGB-120004501, Thm. 3.4.

Comment: Just to follow the encouragement to post a result of one's own!

Answer (score 2):

You can always find a transversal line meeting a family of parallel line segments on the plane such that any 3 can be transversed.

Answer (score 2):

At a party with $4^n$ people and there are either $n$ people who all know each other, or $n$ who are all mutual strangers.

(I used crappy bounds so it could be easily stated. I know the upper bound for $R(n,n)$ is another answer.)

Comment: The upper bound, rather.

Comment: See also https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2017/03/29/r55-%e2%89%a4-48/ straight from OP's blog for the recent result that R(5,5) ≤ 48.  The tweet could be "You can't have 48 people on a party such that no 5 are all acquainted and no 5 are all strangers."

Answer (score 2):

Erdös-Faber-Lovasz conjecture: If $n$ copies of $K_n$ have pairwise intersection of $\leq 1$, you can color all points with $n$ colors.

Comment: I dont think it is already proved. Do you have a complete proof

Comment: That's right, this is an open problem.

Answer (score 2):

$\bar{\rho}$ irreducible Galois rep has finitely many lifts $\rho$ unramified outside of $S$. Proof: $(\rho_2^{-1}\rho_1\rho_2-\rho_1)/\mathcal{l}^r$ is a cocycle.

Answer (score 2):

A group G≠A_n,S_n with a core-free maximal subgroup of index n∈{266,506,759,1045,1288,1463,3795} is sporadic. Proof by GAP. [Any other index?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/336691/34538)

Answer (score 2):

If $S^n$ x $S^n$ minus diag & antidiag self deforms and each (x,y) → (y,x) then n = 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63 or 127 ([Kervaire invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kervaire_invariant#Kervaire_invariant_problem)).

(Stolen from the epigraph of I. M. James, *The topology of Stiefel manifolds* ([1976](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=431239)).)

Answer (score 2):

When playing poker with a quantum decks of cards,
you can only look at one card at a time.

On first sight you might find three aces of hearts,
and two of spades, but when you reveal your hand to
claim the pot you suddenly have nothing but a pair of
twos.

---

**EDIT:** More here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.02817

Comment: This does not fit within 140 characters

Comment: @MattF. question out of date. https://twitter.com/JP_Mc_C/status/1608749294022201346?s=20&t=C7WtmBtGi0qnp7qhZr0qCQ

Answer (score 2):

[Brooks' theorem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X1000289X) and list-coloring variants can be proved using the [combinatorial Nullstellensatz](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/null2.pdf) and a related theorem of [Alon and Tarsi](https://m.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/chrom3.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

[Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) is so big, that its digits contain more information than can be contained within the volume of a human brain

Comment: Understatement of the century...

Comment: And of the last century.

Comment: But does it have a chance for the understatement of the millennium?

Comment: It's less of an understatement when you realize the word "volume" plays an important role: "It's a number so insanely, absurdly huge that storing all the digits of Graham's number in the brain could create a black hole, said John Baez, a mathematical physicist at the University of California, Irvine, who is researching big numbers. (Only so much information can be stored in a given amount of space, and trying to squish more matter into that space creates a black hole, he said.)" http://www.livescience.com/26870-ginormous-numbers-boggle-the-mind.html

Comment: this is perhaps three years too late but I wonder if John Baez is aware that he's "researching big numbers"

Answer (score 1):

There is no smooth surjection from $S^5$ to $S^6$. #Sard

Answer (score 1):

Let $u_0 \ge 2$ be a rational, and $u_{n+1}=⌊u_n⌋(u_n - ⌊u_n⌋ + 1)$.
Does the sequence $(u_n)$ reach an integer? [Link](https://mathoverflow.net/q/377925/34538).
#AlternativeToContinuedFraction

Comment: Cool Tweetable Puzzle

Answer (score -7):

Cogito ergo sum #ReneDescartes

Comment: I find it hilarious that my "tweet" was *too short* for MO. Andere Städtchen, andere Mädchen, I suppose?

Comment: Isn't that more in the area of Tweetable Philosophy?

Comment: Perhaps. Or metamathematics, as I would interpret it. Arguably, that sentence is also at the root of modern scientific method. To those downvoting this answer, I have another one for you: $$\ $$ You are not fun anymore! #MonthyPython

Comment: @Victor Protsak Wait, so "another roof, another proof" [attrib. Erdős] is a play on "andere Städtchen, andere Mädchen"?